# set file encoding attributes of *.txt file on webserver

Tags: webserver, mojibake, file-encodings, github-pages

gh-pages is mobibaking a text file . . . Our CI build server copies some build artifacts to gh-pages.

Locally, I can see that the file-encoding is UTF-8, and if I download the file, and open it, it renders just fine in a text-editor.

However, in Safari, Firefox and Chrome, the special characters (tick, checkmark, etc) are getting mojibaked. How can instruct to use the correct file encoding?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without being instructed, there's no way that the browser can know what file encoding to use for a plain-text file. Setting .htaccess can help, however is web-server dependent. A more portable way is to ensure the text-file starts with a UTF8 byte order mark (BOM). One way to do this is as follows:

```
#!/bin/sh

if [ $# -eq 0 ];
then
        echo usage $0 files ...
        exit 1
fi

for file in $*;
do
        echo "# Processing: $file" 1>&2
        if [ ! -f "$file" ];
        then
                echo Not a file: "$file" 1>&2
                exit 1
        fi
        TYPE=`file - < "$file" | cut -d: -f2`
        if echo "$TYPE" | grep -q '(with BOM)';
        then
                echo "# $file already has BOM, skipping." 1>&2
        else
                ( mv ${file} ${file}~ && uconv -f utf-8 -t utf-8 --add-signature < "${file}~" > "${file}" ) || ( echo Error processing "$file" 1>&2 ; exit 1)
        fi
done
```